# apps-for-android doesn't work

Tags: android

I just check out the apps-for-android project from http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/. After I import into eclipse, I find all is error.

error tip:

> The type Enum is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments .Status>

And it seems there have no refer library. After I add android.jar into refer library, it doesn't work well also. Another error occur('setContentView(R.layout.main);'). remind me that 'R cannot be resolved to a variable', as tip, I import 'R - import android.R;' and then remind me 'main cannot be resolved or is not a field'.

It seems there have no gen file fold. Is that matter?

Comment: @ ahmet alp balkan All file in src/. All remind 'The type Enum is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments .Status>' for the first line 'package com.google.android.xxx;'

Answer (score -1):

You have to find enum point. Maybe some character is skipped (`;` or `}`)